# Visual Studio change Source Control from TFS back to VSS

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2015, visual-sourcesafe, azure-devops

Using Visual Studio 2015 I was previously working on a project which is in an old Visual Source Safe repository.

I needed to connect to a project in Visual Studio Online (Team Foundation Server) and so in Tools -> Options -> Source Control -> Plug In Selection I choose Team Foundation Server and successfully connected to the Visual Studio Online repository pulled down the code, worked on it and checked it in.

The problem comes when I need to access the project in VSS again. I tried to reverse the process. Setting the Plug In Selection back to Visual Source Safe. However even when I don't have a solution open the 'Team Explorer' is still connected to Visual Studio online and I can't connect back to VSS. When I open my VSS based project it is STILL connected to Visual Studio Online as well.

I don't have the option of moving the older project out of VSS just now (not my choice, I'm hoping it's going to change soon but not a choice I can make), and need to carry on working on it. I basically need to disconnect VS from VSO and can't, and can't connect to anything else instead.

Has anyone come across this problem and a solution to it? I've searched but only find answers about disconnecting a project from it's current source control, I don't want to do that, I want each project to remain with it's source control, but I need to be able to choose which source control VS is connected to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I've found AN answer eventually, through trial and error... it's a bit of a faff.

First thing is I forgot that VSS doesn't use the Team Explorer. When I opened the VSS based project the project HAD actually connected to VSS, but the Team Explorer wasn't reflecting that. So I could carry on working on my VSS based project and just ignore Team Explorer.

However I still wanted to disconnect, because it had only been a one-off requirement to connect to that Visual Studio Online project.

What I did was...
1. Log out of my Microsoft account from Visual Studio.
2. Close and re-open Visual Studio.
3. Click close on the prompt to log in to my Microsoft account.
4. THEN the option to delete the connection was available in Team Explorer. Pretty sure it hadn't been there before.
5. Log back in to my Microsoft account.

Unfortunately I had also reset my Microsoft Account password in the trial and error, which I now think was unnecessary. I was just trying to force VS to stop connecting to that repository.

Answer (score 1):

As Team Explorer is not use with VSS you may want to use "Team | Disconnect from TFS" to disconnect. Then switch your control...

Note: As VSS as been completely unsupported for many years you are incurring a significant business risk by staying with it. Have you raised this risk with your executive team? Do they know that their organisational asset is at risk?

Comment: Thanks, I had searched and searched and not found the "Team | Disconnect from TFS" option which is exactly the sort of thing I was looking for. I was looking for an option from Team Explorer and hadn't thought of the Team menu :(

Comment: Yes other options are already being looked at as part of a current review of tools/processes. VSS and the even worse old dos CVS are due to be gone within a year. I've just to carry on using them until the decision/move is made.